# Automatic filter on attribute depending on authenticated user

Tags: api-platform.com

I have an entity called event, the event can have many rooms and a room can have many participants.
If I access all events (with a specific user) I can filter events where the user has no access right (no room with a connection to the specific user) by using extensions.

That works fine.
The response contains all events which have at least one room with access rights.

But If the event has multiple rooms and the user has only access to one room. The response includes both rooms. I created a RoomExtension, but this class will not be invoked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by the fact that filters and extensions only work on the query that retrieves the primary entities. The related entities are retrieved using Doctrines associations wich are part of the domain model that is meant to be the single source of truth for all purposes. What you need is a user-specic view on that model, which in the context of api's usually consists of DTOs.

I think there are basically two solutions:

1. Query primarily for Events and convert the into EventDTOs, then either query for - or filter out - the related Rooms,
2. Query primarily for Rooms, then group them into EventDTOs.

I explain the second solution here because i guesss that it is simpeler and it shoud make your RoomExtension work out of the box, which makes it the better fit to your question, but also because i happen to have built and tested something similar in a [tutorial](https://github.com/metaclass-nl/tutorial-api-platform) so it is a lot less work to write an answer with confidence.

The downside of this solution is that it does not support pagination.

Bucause this solution primarily queries for Rooms, the the operation is on the Room resource. If it where the only collectionOperation of Room it could be like this:

```
(..)
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get_accessible_events"={
 *             "method"="GET",
 *             "path"="/rooms/accessible-events",
 *             "output"=EventDTO::class,
 *             "pagination_enabled"=false
 *         }
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Room {
(..)
```

(This does not have to be your only collectionOperation, you can still have "get", "post" and others).

Right now this still produces a flat collection of Rooms, you need to group them into EventDTOs. The [DTOs page of the docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/) suggest to make a DataTransformer to produce the DTOs, but that only works if your DTOs are one to one with the entities retrieved by the query. But a CollectionDataProvider can do the trick. Because you do not need to adapt the query itself you can simply decorate the default CollectionDataProvider service:

```
namespace App\DataProvider;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Api\OperationType;
use App\DTO\EventDTO;
use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\ContextAwareCollectionDataProviderInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\CollectionDataProviderInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\RestrictedDataProviderInterface;
use App\Entity\Room;

class RoomAccessibleEventCollectionDataProvider implements ContextAwareCollectionDataProviderInterface, RestrictedDataProviderInterface
{
    /** @var CollectionDataProviderInterface */
    private $dataProvider;

    /**
     * @param CollectionDataProviderInterface $dataProvider The built-in orm CollectionDataProvider of API Platform
     */
    public function __construct(CollectionDataProviderInterface $dataProvider)
    {
        $this->dataProvider = $dataProvider;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function supports(string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return Room::class === $resourceClass
            && $operationName == 'get_accessible_events';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getCollection(string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null, array $context = []): array
    {

        $rooms = $this->dataProvider->getCollection($resourceClass, $operationName, $context);

        $dtos = [];
        foreach ($rooms as $room) {
            $key = $room->getId();
            if (isset($dtos[$key])) {
                $dtos[$key]->addRoom($room);
            } else {
                $dto = new EventDTO($room->getEvent());
                $dto->addRoom($room);
                $dtos[$key] = $dto;
            }

        }
 
        return $dtos;
    }
}
```

You do need to configure the service in config/services.yaml:

'App\DataProvider\RoomAccessibleEventCollectionDataProvider':
arguments:
$dataProvider: '@api_platform.doctrine.orm.default.collection_data_provider'

This does not replace the default CollectionDataProvider but adds another one that gets the default one injected.

I guess you can make the EventDTO class yourself now. Then it should work. Filters defined on Room will also work as usual, for example if rooms can be filtered by the date of their event ?event.date[gte]=2020-10-10 will only find rooms with events on or after 2020-10-10 and return their EventDTO's.

However, in the swagger docs the get_accessible_events operations summary and descriptions still come from Room. You can look up how to add a SwaggerDecorator in the docs or take a look at the chapter9-api branch of the [tutorial](https://github.com/metaclass-nl/tutorial-api-platform). The latter also contains complete explanations and tested code for entities, the DTO (Report Model) and an extension for only showing data the user is authorized for, but is not taylored to your questions and would all together be way beyond what a to the point answer.

I can not give you any more hints on this site with respect the other solution because this site will probably see them as an incomplete or unclear answer and punish me for it.